# Autocompleting a setup with custom configuration

Tags: sql-server-2008, installation, setup-deployment

Sorry if my question sounds vague but here is what i want.

### Question

I have a **Microsoft SQL Server 2008** setup which i need to be installed with custom configuration automatically.

Below is how my setup should be installed:-
**Step 1**
[image: Permission to continue setup]

**Step 2**
[image]

**Step 3**
[image]

**Step 4**
[image]

**Step 5**
[image]

**Step 6**
[image]

**Step 7**
[image]

**Step 8**
[image]

**Step 9**
[image]

**Step 10**
[image]

**Step 11**
[image]

**Step 12**
[image]

**Step 13**
[image]

**Step 14**
[image]

**Step 15**
[image]

**Step 16**
[image]

### Problem

I have no idea how to create an EXE or how to give command to the setup do the following **automatically**. Any ideas or clue how to work around this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is where installation from configuration files help ..

All you have to do is to have a configuration file,which describes the actions you posted and a set up file..

When you have those,you can run below command from command prompt...

navigate to a place where setup is located and launch below command..

```
Setup.exe 
/SQLSVCPASSWORD="password" 
/ASSVCPASSWORD="password" 
/AGTSVCPASSWORD="password"
  /ISSVCPASSWORD="password" 
/RSSVCPASSWORD="password" 
/SAPWD="password"
/ConfigurationFile=ConfigurationFile.INI
```

Above are sample parameters for the options you need to install,you can find all parameters here ..

[Install SQL Server 2016 from the Command Prompt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259.aspx)

if you don't have a relevant configuration file,for your version of sql server,you can generate one,using below steps

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239405.aspx